# python speech recognition not getting install

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have being tiring to install python speech recognition for a long time but getting the same problem on running

```
pip install pyaudio
```

**Output:**

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pyaudio did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyaudio

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

As I understand from:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

I had to install 'Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater' so I did. But same result even after
that!
What am I supposes to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```py
pip install pipwin
then
pipwin install pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with just you, everyone faces this.

Here's a fix I hope will work for you:

`pip install pipwin`

`pipwin install pyaudio`

to install `pyaudio` via `pipwin`, sometimes the command doesn't work so try

`pipwin refresh` and run `pipwin install pyaudio` again

If the above steps do not work, try going to [Python Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) and install your system-specific version of pyaudio.

then opening a cmd instance in the directory you installed the package and run
`pip install package`

replace 'package' with the name of the file you downloaded.